# The Free Set Lemma

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

The statement of the lemma is as follows: if $$f: \omega_1 \rightarrow \{x\ :\ x\ \textrm{is finite}\}$$
then there is an uncountable $S \subseteq \omega_1$ such that for all distinct $\alpha,\  \beta \in S$, we have $\alpha \notin f(\beta)$.

My initial attempts at a proof by contradiction didn't get me anywhere because I'm given no information about $f$ at all. Any ideas on what to try next would be great!

**Edit:** A (particularly misleading) typo was fixed; $S$ is meant to be uncountable, not countable.

Comment: @bof: Does it really matter?

Comment: Is a lemma about regressive functions ("pressing down functions) available?

Comment: @bof How about: without loss of generality, assume that $f(\alpha)\cap f(\beta) = \emptyset$. Then let $X = \{\alpha: \exists \beta<\alpha(\beta\in f(\alpha) \vee \alpha\in f(\beta))\}$. If $X$ is stationary, then we can define a regressive function on it in the obvious way. It will follow that some $\alpha$ is in stationarily many $f(\beta)$, which is impossible. If $X$ is not stationary, then there is club $C$ such that for $\alpha, \beta\in C$ neither $\alpha\in f(\beta)$ nor $\beta\in f(\alpha)$.

Comment: @GME How do you justify that "without loss of generality"? If you assume that $f:\omega_1\to\mathcal P(\omega_1)$ satisfies $f(\alpha)\cap f(\beta)=\emptyset$ whenever $\alpha\ne\beta$, then the rest is trivial, and you don't need a cardinality bound on $f(\alpha)$. Since $f(\alpha)$ is free, we may assume that $f(\alpha)$ is countable for each $\alpha$, so $\{\beta:\alpha\in f(\beta)\vee\beta\in f(\alpha)\}$ is countable, so any maximal free set is uncountable.

Comment: @bof, yes, the Pressing Down Lemma is available, and you're right that there's a big typo above! $S$ is uncountable.

Comment: @bof You're right. Once we have my assumption it's trivial to get an uncountable $S$ by recursion. Sorry!

Comment: @GME If you're given the set $X$ that you describe above, how does one define a regressive function on it?

Comment: @VivianBritto If $\alpha\in X$, then there is some $\beta<\alpha$ with the defining property. Then we just map $\alpha$ to the least such $\beta$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By applying the Pressing Down Lemma to the regressive function $\alpha\mapsto\sup f(\alpha)\cap\alpha$, we can get an ordinal $\gamma\lt\omega_1$ and an uncountable (in fact stationary but that doesn't matter) set $A\subseteq\omega_1\setminus\gamma$ such that $f(\alpha)\cap\alpha\subseteq\gamma$ for all $\alpha\in A$. Hence, for distinct ordinals $\alpha,\beta\in A$, $\beta\in f(\alpha)$ implies $\beta\gt\alpha$. Now all we have to do is define a strictly increasing sequence $\langle\alpha_\xi:\xi\lt\omega_1\rangle$ so that $\alpha_\xi\in A\setminus\bigcup_{\eta\lt\xi}f(\alpha_\eta)$.

Comment: I couldn't even define the regressive function to get off the ground; this really helps! Thank you for your input.

Comment: I was trying to write up all the steps of the above proof and got hung up on the final one: how do we know that such a strictly increasing sequence exists, and how do we define it?

Comment: Since $\xi$ is countable and $f(\alpha_\eta)$ is finite, $\bigcup_{\eta\lt\xi}f(\alpha_\eta)$ is countable, so $\sup\bigcup_{\eta\lt\xi}f(\alpha_\eta)\lt\omega_1$ while $\sup A=\omega_1$.

Comment: Sorry for the repeated questions, but I just want to make sure I have the picture clear: the Pressing Down Lemma gives us an uncountable set $A$ "above" some ordinal $\gamma$, with the range of $f(\alpha)\cap\alpha$ for all $\alpha\in A$ bounded above by $\gamma$. I'm not clear then how we can talk about a $\beta\in A$ and have $\beta\in f(\alpha)$ also? For each $\beta\in A$, is it not the case that $\beta > \gamma > f(\alpha)$ for any $\alpha\in A$? Where is my mistake here?

Comment: And can you please clarify the edit you made where you changed the requirement on the $\alpha_{\xi}$? Your previous definition made more sense to me.

Comment: Before the edit, the requirement on $\alpha_\xi$ was merely that $\alpha_\xi\notin\bigcup_{\eta\lt\xi}f(a_\eta)$. The edit adds to that the requirement that $\alpha_\xi\in A$. I don't understand why it "made more sense" without requiring $\alpha_\xi\in A$. What would be the point of using the Pressing Down Lemma to obtain the set $A$ if in the end we're going to define the free set without referring to $A$?

Comment: "For each $\beta\in A$, is it not the case that $\beta\gt\gamma\gt f(\alpha)$ for any $\alpha\in A$?" I don't see why, unless there is some assumption about $f$ that you left out when you stated the question. We know that $f(\alpha)\cap\alpha$ is contained in $\gamma$, so it's disjoint from $A$. All we know about $f(\alpha)\setminus\alpha$ is that it's a finite set. Of course, if we assumed $f(\alpha)\subseteq\alpha$ to start with, then $A$ itself would be a free set, so the proof would be one line shorter.

Comment: Things are starting to make more sense now - I totally forgot that we were working with the collection of finite sets, and instead was playing around in $\omega_1$. Your comment above clears things up a lot, but there's something I'm still not seeing: in the answer, did you mean "$\beta\in f(\alpha)\cap\alpha$ implies $\beta >\alpha$"? I'm thinking of a case like $f(\alpha) = \alpha - 1$ as a counterexample. Whereas, if the condition is $\beta\in f(\alpha)\cap\alpha$, we know that $\beta$ survives the intersection, so it must be larger. Is this right?

Comment: I meant what I said. Suppose $\alpha,\beta$ are distinct elements of $A$, and $ \beta\in f(\alpha)$. The three *a priori* possibilities are (i) $\beta=\alpha$, (ii) $\beta\lt\alpha$, (iii) $\beta\gt\alpha$. We rule out (i) because I said $\alpha$ and $\beta$ were distinct. We rule out (ii) because, if $\beta\lt\alpha$, then $\beta\in f(\alpha)\cap\alpha\subseteq\gamma$, but $\beta\in\gamma$ is impossible since $\beta\in A$. The only possibility is (iii), $\beta\gt\alpha$.

Comment: Ah, I see now. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I assume you mean
$$f:\omega_1\to\{x\subseteq\omega_1:|x|\lt\omega\}.$$
For some $n\lt\omega$, there is an uncountable set $V\subseteq\omega_1$ such that $|f(\beta)|\lt n$ for all $\beta\in V$. Now consider the graph $G$ with vertex set $V$ and edge set $E=\{\{\alpha,\beta\}:\alpha\lt\beta\text{ and }\alpha\in f(\beta)\}$. You can easily show (by transfinite induction) that the graph $G$ is $n$-colorable, i.e., the vertex set $V$ is the union of $n$ independent sets; so there is an uncountable independent set $W\subseteq V$. For each $\beta\in W$, the set $f(\beta)\cap W$ contains only ordinals greater than (or equal to) $\beta$. Now it's easy to see that there is an uncountable free set $S\subseteq W$.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a proof using the Erdős-Rado partition theorem $\omega_1\to(\omega+1,\,\omega_1)^2$, or rather its corollary $\omega_1\to(\omega+1,\,\omega,\,\omega_1)^2$. For $\alpha,\beta\in\omega_1,\,\alpha\lt\beta$, put the pair $\{\alpha,\beta\}$ in $C_1$ if $\alpha\in f(\beta)$, in $C_2$ if $\beta\in f(\alpha)$, in $C_3$ if $\alpha\notin f(\beta)$ and $\beta\notin f(\alpha)$; so $[\omega_1]^2=C_1\cup C_2\cup C_3$. Then there is a set $S\subseteq\omega_1$ such that, writing $\operatorname{tp}S$ for the order type of $S$, either (1) $[S]^2\subseteq C_1$ and $\operatorname{tp}S=\omega+1$, or (2) $[S]^2\subseteq C_2$ and $\operatorname{tp}S=\omega$, or (3) $[S]^2\subseteq C_3$ and $\operatorname{tp}S=\omega_1$. But (1) and (2) are impossible because of the finiteness assumption on $f$, so (3) holds and $S$ is an uncountable free set.

Comment: This is really elegant! Unfortunately, I don't have access to the Erdos-Rado partition theorem. You commented above asking about the Pressing Down Lemma; is there a way to use that instead?

Comment: Yes, the third answer I posted uses the Pressing Down Lemma. That's probably the way you are expected to do the problem. Personally I like the first one I posted, which uses nothing.